# How can I get an agent to decay as multiple agents feed on it?

Tags: netlogo

In my model I have some agents which act as food items with a set energy. These are fed upon by a number of turtle breeds who each have their own food-energy which is less than the energy of the food item.

The code for the feeding agents is as follows:

```
to eat
  ifelse [food-energy] of myfood > 1.5 [
  set food-energy  1.5]
end
```

and the associated code for the food item to decay is:

```
to decay
  if any? turtles-here [set food-energy 
  (1.5 * count feeders-here with  [myfood = myself]
end
```

The problem occurs if the energy of the food is not an exact multiple of the amount of energy the feeders can consume. So for example it can go down to 1 and this results in the feeders taking 1.5 units which should be impossible. This is exacerbated when I have different breeds with different food energies (i.e. < or > 1.5).

So my question is how can I get this things to balance?

Comment: I am not entirely sure what decay is supposed to do since it seems to create energy rather than reduce it. However, my best guess is that you want a construction something like `set out-value min (list 1.5 in-value)`. That is, if the in-value is already than 1.5, then the out-value will be the same as the in-value, but will be 1.5 if the in-value is larger.

Comment: I should have said that I am running the decay function in reverse. If you look at my answer below you may get an idea of how this works in that I have two variables, meat and food-energy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your responses. I'll try to implement them. This is one inelegant workaround that worked for me:

```
to eat
ifelse (food-energy / capacity) < 1 and [meat] of myfood > capacity [
set food-energy  1.5] [set food-energy [meat] of myfood
ask myfood [set shape "square"]]  
if (food-energy / capacity) = 1 [
set color white]
if (food-energy > 0 and food-energy / capacity < 1) 
[ set color white ]
end
```

This was initially causing a problem such that when the food energy went down to 0 and I asked it to die any animal looking at the [meat] of myfood lost it's target and I got an error. So I made the animals break this connection once their colour was white.

```
to ignore
 set myfood nobody
 set food-energy food-energy * 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to study the Wolf-Sheep Predation model.  This is the first NetLogo tutorial: http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/tutorial1.html  There are five versions of increasing complexity in the NetLogo Models Library, which are covered in chapter 4 of Wilensky and Rand (2015), which you should read.
2. See some related material here:
   http://jasss.soc.surrey.ac.uk/14/2/5.html

Some hints follow, but many details need filling in.

```
breed [feeders feeder]
patches-own [ food-energy ]
feeders-own [ myfood ]
to setup
  ca
  ask patches [set food-energy random 50]
  create-feeders 500 [
    move-to one-of patches
    set myfood one-of patches
  ]
end

to go
  ask feeders [move]
  ask feeders [feed]
  ask patches [growback]
end

to move ;how shd they move?
  rt random 20
  left random 40
  fd 1
  ;shd movement cost energy?
end

to feed
  if (patch-here = myfood) [
    let _extracted min (list food-energy 1.5)
    set food-energy (food-energy - _extracted)
  ]
end

to growback
  ;do you want growback?
end
```